# Apps which can be run in China and the rest of the world

Tags: mysql, node.js, networking, loopbackjs

I need an infrastructure to handle the scenario that my web or mobile apps can access (around the world, including people inside China) my Web API which is located outside China. We have clients around the world (China, USA, Australia,etc), we want to use one API and database to centralize all the data, instead have another service in China. I know the best case is to host the server inside China, but it will affect other customers which are located outside China (very slow). Any good advice ?

Comment: You would better ask this on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/. You can use your http://stackoverflow.com/ account for this, linking it to these communities too. The "historical root" of the stackechange network, SO (StackOverflow), is for programming questions.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: You're welcome. You might now delete your question here, and (don't take this personally!) I flagged it as "should be closed" because "out of topic", because "Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault. " That's part of your and my job, to help make the "stack exchange" network of sites so effective, for relevant answers from qualified people to questions asked at the right place, with so low noise.